# in haskell pasing error at l

Tags: haskell

i compiler the code agin and agin first time say parse error on mmult and then on l what the problem exactly i don't know

```
    mmult :: (Ix i, Num a) => Array (i, i) a -> Array (i, i) a -> Array (i, i) a 
    mmult x y 
        | x1 /= y0 || x1' /= y0'  = error "range mismatch"
        | otherwise               = array ((x0, y1), (x0', y1')) l where
            ((x0, x1), (x0', x1')) = bounds x
            ((y0, y1), (y0', y1')) = bounds y
            ir = range (x0, x0')
            jr = range (y1, y1')
            kr = range (x1, x1')
            l  = [((i, j), sum [x ! (i, k) * y ! (k, j)  | k <- kr] ) | i <- ir, j <- jr]
```

please help me

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a couple close brackets on the end of the last line.

Answer (score 2):

- The actual error may be to do with what is immediately preceding this function.

  - It would help us if you showed us the code immediately before this function.
- It may be that `mmult` is indented differently to whatever precedes it.
- Perhaps you are mixing tabs and spaces.

  - In this case, the simplest thing is to get rid of the tabs and use only spaces to indent.

---

```
l  = [((i, j), sum [x ! (i, k) * y ! (k, j) )| k <- kr]
```

This should probably be

```
l  = [((i, j), sum [x ! (i, k) * y ! (k, j)  | k <- kr] ) | i <- ir, j <- jr]
```

Comment: thr code have error on l

Comment: 1. See edit. 2. Editing your question so that answers to your original question no longer make sense is rude.

Comment: thanx but it still there